# Superkey vs. Candidate key

Tags: sql, database, database-design, ddl

What difference between Super and Candidate key in ERDB?

Comment: Superkey and Candidate Key are relational database model terms. What does "ERDB" mean? Maybe you are referring to the Entity Relationship (ER) model which is a set of conventions for drawing pictures about data. The ER model is something different from the relational model.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

candidate key is a **minimal** superkey

Comment: +1, plus it would be good to define "minimal" here since it's non-intuitive. For example in table (a,b,c), with (a) being unique and also (b,c) being unique, both (a) and (b,c) should be candidate keys.

Comment: Minimal in the sense that if one attribute from the candidate key is removed,  the row cannot be uniquely identified anymore.

Answer (score 22):

A superkey is a set of columns that uniquely identifies a row.  A Candidate key would be a MINIMAL set of columns that uniquely identifies a row.  So essentially a Superkey is a Candidate key with extra unnecessary columns in it.

Comment: "a Superkey is a Candidate key with extra unnecessary columns" -- the extra columns may actually be necessary to reference the table and ensure data integrity e.g. `(employee_ID)` is unique but a key on `(employee_ID, department_name)` may be required for certain tables that restrict employees according to their department.

Answer (score 4):

- Candidate key = minimal key to identify a row
- Super key = at least as wide as a candidate key

For me, a super key would generally introduce ambiguities over a candidate key

Comment: A candidate key is a minimal superkey. So a superkey isn't strictly "wider" because a candidate key is a superkey too.

Comment: @david: isn't "minimal superkey" an oxymoron?

Comment: "generally introduce ambiguities" -- what do you mean? For example, in this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938736/enforce-constraints-between-tables/3940708#3940708) the EmployeeDepartments table has a candidate key `(employee_ID)` and a superkey `(employee_department_name, employee_ID)`. Both are required for data integrity, where's the ambiguity?

Comment: @onedaywhen: (employee_department_name, employee_ID) means you can have the same employee_ID for multiple employee_department_name values. How can employee_ID itself be a unique key then?

Comment: @gbn: `(employee_department_name, employee_ID)` is a key (a superkey) because `(employee_ID)` is in itself a key (a candidate key), so no it is not possible to have the same employee_ID for multiple employee_department_name values.

Comment: @gbn: ...`employee_department_name` is "brought in" to the key so that it can be referenced (via a foreign key) from another table. So my point is that a superkey does have a practical use in data integrity constraints.

Comment: @onedaywhen: We'll have to disagree then.

Comment: @gbn: If you insist :) but in parting note this is a common enough technique e.g. see this article (http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/unique-experiences!/), section captioned, "Overlapping Uniqueness Constraints".

Comment: @onedaywhen: I have no objection to multiple and/or overlapping unique keys. I do object to the term "superkey" when plainly (employee_department_name, employee_ID) does not uniquely identify a row *if* (employee_ID) is already the primary key. It is neither a candidate nor super key, even if it is defined unique for use by an FK.

Comment: @gbn: so we agree it fits the definition of "superkey", it's just that you have a problem with the whole concept of superkeys? I'm not here to change you belief system, peace :)

Comment: @gbn: FWIW I myself believe in using natural keys but I'm dead against supernatural keys ;)

Comment: You don't define "minimal" & these are circular.

Answer (score 2):

**Let's keep it simple**

**SuperKey** - A set of keys that uniquely defines a `row`.So out of all the attributes if even any single one is `unique` then all the subsets having that unique attribute falls under `superkey`.

**Candidate Key** - A `superkey` out of which no further subset can be derived which can identify the `rows uniquely`, Or we can simply say that it is the `minimal superkey`.

Answer (score 0):

In nutshell: **CANDIDATE KEY is a minimal SUPER KEY.**

Where Super key is the combination of columns(or attributes) that uniquely identify any record(or tuple) in a relation(table) in RDBMS.

---

For instance, consider the following dependencies in a table having columns A, B, C and D
*(Giving this table just for a quick example so not covering all dependencies that R could have).*

**Attribute set (Determinant)**---Can Identify--->**(Dependent)**

A-----> AD

B-----> ABCD

C-----> CD

AC----->ACD

AB----->ABCD

ABC----->ABCD

BCD----->ABCD

---

Now, B, AB, ABC, BCD identifies all columns so those four qualify for the super key.

But, **B⊂AB; B⊂ABC; B⊂BCD** hence AB, ABC, and BCD disqualified for CANDIDATE KEY as their subsets could identify the relation, so they aren't minimal and hence only B is the candidate key, not the others.