# Unique key vs Candidate key / Superkey (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

The following SQL code creates two tables, (A) `__tableA__`, (B) `__tableB__`. Both tables contain exactly 2 unique keys, named `k1` and `k2`.

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'version';    # 5.0.51b

CREATE TABLE __tableA__ (`a` INT, `b` INT,
  UNIQUE KEY `k1`(`a`),
  UNIQUE KEY `k2`(`a`,`b`)
);                                       # Key_name      Column_name
                                         # -------------------------
SHOW KEYS FROM __tableA__;               # k1            a
                                         # k2            a
                                         # k2            b
CREATE TABLE __tableB__ (`a` INT,
  UNIQUE KEY `k1`(`a`),
  UNIQUE KEY `k2`(`a`)
);                                       # Key_name      Column_name
                                         # -------------------------
SHOW KEYS FROM __tableB__;               # k1            a
                                         # k2            a

DROP TABLE __tableA__;     # cleanup
DROP TABLE __tableB__;     #
```

As shown by the `SHOW KEYS` command, the sets of attributes (columns) of keys `k1` and `k2` are

- A: `{a}` and `{a,b}`, respectively,
- B: `{a}` and `{a}`, respectively.

This suggests the conclusion that, in MySQL, **the concept of *unique key* does NOT correspond to either of the concepts of *candidate key* / *superkey***:
In case (A),  `k1` and `k2` cannot be candidate keys because `{a} ⊂ {a,b}` (thus the set of attributes of `k2` is not minimal).
In case (B), `k1` and `k2` cannot be superkeys because they are different keys with identical sets of attributes.

My **question**: Is this conclusion correct? If so, which authoritative source does state it clearly?

Comment: To be honest I never heard about these 2 concepts, so in the first place thank you for making me improve.

Then, after reading a little bit about it, my question is the following: what is, for you, the reason that a unique index is not a superkey?

Comment: Candidate Key/Superkey are data-modeling terms that are rarelly related to RDBMS implementation. What do you mean by Superkey?

Comment: Maybe this question is more apropriate for dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087654/superkey-vs-candidate-key

Comment: @Songo: _Superkey vs Candidate key_ is no problem, it is well documented.

Comment: @Darhazer: There seem to be more related questions on [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unique%20key%20candidate%20key%20superkey) than on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=unique%20key%20candidate%20key%20superkey).

Comment: You're asking something weird ;P `UNIQUE KEY `k2`(`a`,`b`)` is a candidate key because you can't have two records with the same `a`, `b` pair. Same in case (b). Also, it's not clear why you say they "aren't superkeys because they are different keys". They __are__ different keys, you can't consider them as one superkey...

Comment: @meze: By definition, `k2` cannot be a candidate key because its set of attributes is not minimal - it contains the set of attributes of `k1`. In case (B), it follows from the definition of a superkey that a table with exactly one attribute (column) `a` always contains exactly one superkey - namely the singleton set `{a}`. Thus, it cannot contain 2 distinct superkeys.

Comment: @paon Still don't get. How can you know it's not minimal if you don't what data you store. If the k2 has (favorite_color, SSN) then it's not a candidate key. If it has (country, zip) then it is a candidate key. That's how i understand it.

Comment: @meze: By definition, the minimality is taken w.r.t. sets of attributes. Whether a set of attributes forms a candidate key or not cannot be, in general, derived from the (current) set of table rows. A candidate key is something that has to be put as a constraint for possible table states.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. In SQL, the set of columns defined in a uniqueness constraint is not necessarily a key (minimal superkey) and certainly isn't if some proper subset of those columns also has a uniqueness constraint on it.

Unlike standard SQL a peculiarity of MySQL syntax is that it uses "KEY" as a synonym for "INDEX", which seems to suggest that the authors of MySQL either don't know or don't care what a key is!